# Benefits of Java ClassLoader delegation model?

Tags: java

As I know that ClassLoader first check if the class has been loaded, if not then  immediately delegate this check to its parent ClassLoader.But at the end all the classes are  loaded by the Bootstrap. why we are delegating and what are benefits we are achieving by this  ?

Comment: "at the end all the classes are loaded by the Bootstrap" isn't true. If it was true there would be no point in having other class loaders at all, let alone a delegation model.

Comment: If parent ClassLoader not able to load then it  deligate it to child .But the questions is what  benifits we are getting by this? I want to know the reasons so please do not mark it down.

Comment: No, it delegates to its parent first.  If that fails then it tries to load the class itself.  It never delegates to a child.

Comment: `But at the end all the classes are loaded by the Bootstrap.` is not true, the bootstrap class loader is an integral part of the JVM and is responsible for loading trusted classes (e.g. basic Java class library classes). Also `ClassLoader first check if the class has been loaded, if not then immediately delegate this check to its parent ClassLoader`, is not always true,  The class loaders used to load servlets in a servlet engine (e.g. Tomcat), for example, are developed in such a way that they attempt to load a class directly before delegating the request.

Answer (score 4):

Implementation need not always delegate to parent class loader. It depends on the requirement. If requirements needs that a class should be loaded by the class loader implementation, it can load it, even if its already loaded by another class loader.

A class (and instances) loaded by ClassLoader_1 will not be accessible by instance loaded by another ClassLoader_2. This provides additional security.

For example, in a browser, each domain can be given their own unique classloader (by the browser implementation). The core java classes can be delegated to Boot Class loader to optimize core classes as they wont be different. And all these class loaders can loaded inside a single JVM for optimal use of resources.

Now, instances/classes of one domain wont be able access instances of other domain which are loaded by another class loader. They will receive ClassCastException if they access cross site.

Hierarchy ensures that classes loaded by parent are compatible across children

You can access current context class loader from the execution Thread using following

```
Thread.getContextClassLoader();
```

You can access the class loader which loaded an object using following

```
Object o = ....
o.getClass().getClassLoader();
```

Answer (score 1):

By *optionally* delegating to another class loader, class loaders implement the Decorator design pattern. This makes it easier to add functionality to an existing class loader.

The alternative would be that any class loader implemented by an application programmer would have to implement **all** the class loading logic. As class loading must be done carefully to avoid security weaknesses, application programmers would probably introduce numerous security problems.